# How to switch the base of a path using pathlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I am trying to get a part of a path by removing the base, currently this is what I'm doing:

```py
original = '/tmp/asd/asdqwe/file'
base = '/tmp/asd/'
wanted_part = original.strip(base)
```

Unfortunately, instead of getting `'asdqwe/file'`  I'm getting `'qwefile'`, for some reason strip works weird and I don't get it.

The best solution for my problem would be using `pathlib.Path` because my function gets its proprieties as paths, and the return value converting the trimmed string into Path after adding a new base path.
But if no pathlib solution is available a string one would also be great, currently I'm dealing with a weird bug...

Comment: what weird bug? strip doesnt remove a string of chars, string will take a sequence of chars and keep removing them until it doesnt find any of them. So after removing the part your interested in the next letter is a and strip will say ok is this in the sequence to remove. yes it is so its remove, then same again with the s and d, only when it reaches queue does it say ok dont remove this char

Comment: from the python documentation on `str.strip()`: The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

Comment: You are right about my strip misuse, I'm thinking about omitting it from the question, but the answers given related to that problem..
Anyhow the answer I marked as accepted gave a pathlib answer, so my question is answered good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misinterpreting how [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) works. The method will remove all characters specified in the argument from the "edges" of the target string, regardless of the order in which they are specified:

```
original = '/tmp/asd/asdqwe/file'
base = '/tmp/asd/'
wanted_part = original.strip(base)
print(wanted_part)
# qwe/file
```

What you would like to do is probably a slicing:

```
wanted_part = original[len(base):]
print(wanted_part)
# asdqwe/file
```

---

Or, using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#methods-and-properties):

```
from pathlib import Path

original = Path('/tmp/asd/asdqwe/file')
base = Path('/tmp/asd/')

wanted_part = original.relative_to(base)
print(wanted_part)
# asdqwe/file
```

Answer (score 0):

strip will remove a sequnce of chars, not a string prefix or suffix, so it will keep removing anychars in the sequence you passed. Instaed you can test if the original starts with your base and if it does then just take the remaining chars of the string which are the chars after the length of the base.

```py
original = '/tmp/asd/asdqwe/file'
base = '/tmp/asd/'
if original.startswith(base):
    wanted_part = original[len(base):]
    print(wanted_part)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
asdqwe/file
```